# Prevent display of MDI child title bar after a second MDI child is closed

Tags: vb.net, forms, mdi

In a Win Form MDI app, I want to have MDI child forms appear maximized within the parent container, without their own title bars. Everything works fine until I open a second child form from the first child form, and then close the second child form -- the first child form's title bar is then displayed.

I created a small test project containing three forms - frmParent, frmChild1 and frmChild2. frmParent contains a MenuStrip with options to open frmChild1, open frmChild2 and exit. FrmChild1 contains two buttons - Open frmChild2, and Close. frmChild2 contains a single button Close.

frmParent code:

```
Private Sub mnuChild1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuChild1.Click
    Dim lfrmChild1 As New frmChild1
    lfrmChild1.MdiParent = Me
    lfrmChild1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    lfrmChild1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub mnuChild2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuChild2.Click
    Dim lfrmChild2 As New frmChild2
    lfrmChild2.MdiParent = Me
    lfrmChild2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    lfrmChild2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub mnuExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

frmChild1 code:

```
Private Sub btnCloseChild1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCloseChild1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnOpenChild2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenChild2.Click
    Dim lfrmChild2 As New frmChild2
    lfrmChild2.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
    lfrmChild2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    lfrmChild2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub frmChild1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
End Sub
```

frmChild2 code:

```
Private Sub btnCloseChild2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCloseChild2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub frmChild2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
End Sub
```

How can I prevent frmChild1's title bar from being displayed after frmChild2 is closed, having been opened from frmChild1?

Comment: Okay, I've got the title bar problem resolved -- I changed the child forms' FormBorderStyle to None, and set ControlBox, MaximizeBox and MinimizeBox to False, Opening a child form only requiresDim lfrmChild1 As New frmChild1
        lfrmChild1.MdiParent = Me
        lfrmChild1.Show()

Comment: I got interrupted -- here's the full comment: Okay, I've got the title bar problem resolved -- I changed the child forms' FormBorderStyle to None, and set ControlBox, MaximizeBox and MinimizeBox to False, Opening a child form only requires Dim lfrmChild1 As New frmChild1, lfrmChild1.MdiParent = Me, and lfrmChild1.Show(). Now my only remaining problem is that when a child is opened maximized  from another child, its location is set to (-8, -31) instead of (0, 0). I've opened an incident with MS to resolve, and will update here when I have an answer.

Comment: BTW, the child being opened has to have the following coded in its Load event: Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Me.MaximizeBox = False